# Vote to close, delete or leave my question open?

Tags: support, specific-question

For 25 days of using my Delphi IDE after reporting [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753533/ide-crashes-with-tooltip-expression-evaluation) it has not happened again.

It obviously was a software glitch, but I can't reproduce it. Nobody else seems to have experienced it either.

Do I flag my question as 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced', do I delete it, or leave it open?

Comment: You might as well delete it. If you leave it alone for a year it'll be [automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) unless it gets votes or answers. Closing it will only speed up that process. If you don't think there'll be any useful answers in the foreseeable future there's no real reason to keep it around.

Comment: Flagging your own question for deletion is something you should not do! It will end up in a review queue, others will have to vote about it and it will take up their time. If you want to delete it, just delete it. If you yourself can't even reproduce it, I'd just close it. An alternative would be to edit your question with the information that it spontaneously resolved itself. That might help future readers, until the question is automatically closed.

Comment: voted: 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced' for you

Comment: Well someone went and upvoted it so it won't be automatically deleted now, meaning you do have a choice to keep it around if you want.

Comment: The question is now close voted. I have no issue with that, but the (3 out of 5) close reason *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic* is incorrect. (greg-449, thebluefox, JoseK)

Comment: Yeah, that's not a very good reason in my opinion but re-opening it only to close it again with a more correct reason is just going to create noise in the review queues that are already overflowing.

Comment: @Ivarni. Of course. I didn't imply that.